# STI vs Polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am confuse while using STI and Polymorphic association, so When should I use STI or Polymorphic associations?

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/single-table-inheritance-vs-polymorphic-associations-in-rails-af3a07a204f2

Comment: There is also a third option which is often overlooked which is using a set of discrete join tables. So to join A and B with C you would use the tables AC and BC. This allows you to use foreign keys and cascades.

Comment: now since rails 6.1 there is a middle ground between STI vs Polymorphic which is [Delegated Type](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html)

Answer (score 4):

Following are the difference scenarios which would help you to take a decision

1. **Database structure.** STI uses only one table for all classes in the
   relationship, while polymorphic associations use a table per class.
   Each method has its own advantages and disadvantages as the
   application grows.
2. **Shared data or state.** STI is a great option if your models have many
   shared attributes. Otherwise a polymorphic association is probably
   the better choice.
3. **Future concerns.** Consider how your application might change and
   grow. If you’re considering STI but think you’ll add models or model
   fields that deviate from the shared structure, you might want to
   rethink your plan. If you think your structure is likely to remain
   the same, STI will generally be faster for querying.
4. **Data integrity.** If data is not going to be contained (one
   application using your database), polymorphic association is
   probably a bad choice because your data will be compromised.

If you want to more deatils about STI and Polymorpic association then you could use [this link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/single-table-inheritance-vs-polymorphic-associations-in-rails-af3a07a204f2), it will give clear idea of using it.

Comment: Data integrity is a problem even if you have one application that is running on multiple threads simultaneously. Which is pretty much every rails app not running on Webbrick. Race conditions can and will occur so you cannot trust the application to maintain the integrity of the database.

Comment: now since rails 6.1 there is a middle ground between STI vs Polymorphic which is [Delegated Type](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html)

Answer (score 1):

In short...

- you should use STI when your app doesn't need to scale or change (a lot) and your models have many shared attributes.
- you should use Polymorpic when your app has simple queries and the integrity of your data is not crucial.

I hope it useful for you. :)